# Elastic Beanstalk is creating instance with default jvm as Corretto 8 with solution stack 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.8 running Corretto 11

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application to an Elastic Beanstalk. But the Stack health shows as degraded. While checking the causes I found the error message "Following services are not running: web."
While analyzing the logs I found that the application did not run due to classes not being compatible. Error below:
"web: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/reportservice/ReportServiceApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"

So I checked the JVM on the EC2 instance created and found that the default jvm on the instance was Corretto 8.

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

/*Retrieve the latest Amazon EC2 AMI id with prefix "Amazon2_x64_BaseImage2" */
data "aws_ami" "amazon2_baseimage2_ami" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["Amazon2_x64_BaseImage2-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "root-device-type"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "warranty_solutions_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}-${var.application_environment}"
}

locals {
  date_time = "${formatdate("YYYYMMDD_hh:mm:ss", timestamp())}"

  # EC2 VPC Settings
  ec2_vpc_settings = [
    {
      name  = "VPCId"
      value = var.vpc_id
    },
    {
      name  = "AssociatePublicIpAddress"
      value = "false"
    },
    {
      name  = "Subnets"
      value = join(",", var.service_subnets)
    }
  ]

  # Autoscaling Launch Configuration Settings
  autoscaling_launch_configuration_settings = [
    {
      name  = "SecurityGroups"
      value = join(",", var.security_groups)
    },
    {
      name  = "IamInstanceProfile"
      value = var.instance_profile_arn
    },
    {
      name  = "InstanceType"
      value = var.instance_type
    },
    {
      name  = "EC2KeyName"
      value = var.ec2_keypair_name
    },
    {
      name  = "ImageId"
      value = data.aws_ami.amazon2_baseimage2_ami.id // Amazon linux machine image ID
    }
  ]

  # Settings for beanstalk managed elb only
  beanstalk_elb_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
      name      = "ELBSubnets"
      value     = join(",", sort(var.elb_public_subnets))
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "Port"
      value     = var.application_port
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "Protocol"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_type == "network" ? "TCP" : "HTTP"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
      name      = "ELBScheme"
      value     = var.elb_scheme
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "HealthCheckPath"
      value     = var.healthcheck_url
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "HealthCheckInterval"
      value     = var.healthcheck_interval
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "HealthyThresholdCount"
      value     = var.healthcheck_healthy_threshold_count
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "UnhealthyThresholdCount"
      value     = var.healthcheck_unhealthy_threshold_count
    }
  ]
  generic_elb_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
      name      = "LoadBalancerType"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_type
    }
  ]
  generic_alb_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
      name      = "SecurityGroups"
      #      value     = join(",", sort(local.alb_security_group_list))
      value     = join(",", sort(var.alb_security_groups))
      #      value     = "${aws_security_group.ProdReg_DB2_SG.id}, ${join(",", ${var.security_groups})}"
    }
  ]
  alb_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:default"
      name      = "ListenerEnabled"
      value     = var.enable_http || var.loadbalancer_certificate_arn == "" ? "true" : "false"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
      name      = "ManagedSecurityGroup"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_managed_security_group
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "ListenerEnabled"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_certificate_arn == "" ? "false" : "true"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "Protocol"
      value     = "HTTPS"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "SSLCertificateArns"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_certificate_arn
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "SSLPolicy"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_type == "application" ? var.loadbalancer_ssl_policy : ""
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https"
      name      = "Port"
      value     = var.application_port
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https"
      name      = "Protocol"
      value     = "HTTPS"
    },

    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https"
      name      = "HealthCheckPath"
      value     = var.healthcheck_url
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
      name      = "HealthCheckTimeout"
      value     = var.healthcheck_timeout
    }
  ]
  nlb_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:default"
      name      = "ListenerEnabled"
      value     = var.enable_http
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https"
      name      = "Port"
      value     = var.application_port
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "ListenerEnabled"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_certificate_arn == "" ? "false" : "true"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "Protocol"
      value     = "TCP"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "SSLCertificateArns"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_certificate_arn
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
      name      = "SSLPolicy"
      value     = ""
    }
  ]

  # Select elb configuration depending on loadbalancer_type
  elb_settings_nlb   = var.loadbalancer_type == "network" ? concat(local.nlb_settings, local.generic_elb_settings, local.beanstalk_elb_settings) : []
  elb_settings_alb   = var.loadbalancer_type == "application" ? concat(local.alb_settings, local.generic_alb_settings, local.generic_elb_settings, local.beanstalk_elb_settings) : []
  # If the tier is "WebServer" add the elb_settings, otherwise exclude them
  elb_settings_final = var.tier == "WebServer" ? concat(local.elb_settings_nlb, local.elb_settings_alb) : []
}

//Within that bucket, we can add the application build file as an object:
resource "aws_s3_object" "wty_report_bucket_object" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.warranty_solutions_bucket.id
  key    = "${var.bucket_key}_${local.date_time}.zip"
  source = var.build_source_filename
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "wty-report-service-app" {
  name        = var.application_name
  description = var.application_desc
  appversion_lifecycle {
    delete_source_from_s3 = true
    service_role          = var.service_role_arn
    max_count             = 100
  }
  tags = {
    component = var.component
  }
}

//create a version, In which we can tell AWS where to find our application:
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "wty_report_service_api_version" {
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.wty-report-service-app.name
  bucket      = data.aws_s3_bucket.warranty_solutions_bucket.id
  key         = aws_s3_object.wty_report_bucket_object.id
  name        = "build_${local.date_time}"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "wty-report-service-dev" {
  name                = "${var.application_name}-${var.application_environment}"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.wty-report-service-app.name
  /*appversion_lifecycle {
    delete_source_from_s3 = true
    service_role          = var.service_role_arn
    max_count             = 100
  }*/
  solution_stack_name = var.ebs_solution_stack
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.wty_report_service_api_version.name
  tier                = var.tier

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "JavaVersion"
    value     = "11"
  }

  tags = {
    component  = var.component
    created_by = "Terraform"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE"
    value     = "devl"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "SPRING_CONFIG_NAME"
    value     = "application-devl.properties"
  }
  #---------------------------------
  # Adding EC2 VPC Settings
  #---------------------------------
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = local.ec2_vpc_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
      name      = setting.value["name"]
      value     = setting.value["value"]
    }
  }

  #---------------------------------------------------
  # Adding Autoscaling: Launch Configuration Settings
  #---------------------------------------------------
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = local.autoscaling_launch_configuration_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name      = setting.value["name"]
      value     = setting.value["value"]
    }
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:instances"
    name      = "InstanceTypes"
    value     = var.instance_type
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "Availability Zones"
    value     = "Any 2"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = "1"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = "2"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }

  #---------------------------------
  # Adding Autoscaling Update Policy
  #---------------------------------
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.autoscaling_update_policy
    content {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate"
      name      = setting.key
      value     = setting.value
    }
  }

  #---------------------------------
  # Adding Elastic Beanstalk Commands
  #---------------------------------
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.ebs_command_settings
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"
      name      = setting.key
      value     = setting.value
    }
  }

  #---------------------------------
  # Adding Environment variables
  #---------------------------------
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.env_vars
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
      name      = setting.key
      value     = setting.value
    }
  }

  ############################################################################
  ##  Sets up Elastic Beanstalk to stream environment health information
  ##  to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.
  ##  Works only for environments that have enhanced health reporting enabled.
  ############################################################################

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "StreamLogs"
    value     = var.enable_stream_logs ? "true" : "false"
  }
  # DeleteOnTerminate: Delete the log group when the environment is
  # terminated. Default is false. If false, the health data is kept
  # RetentionInDays days.
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "DeleteOnTerminate"
    value     = var.logs_delete_on_terminate ? "true" : "false"
  }
  # RetentionInDays: The number of days to keep the archived health data
  # before it expires, if DeleteOnTerminate isn't set. Default is 7 days.
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "RetentionInDays"
    value     = var.logs_retention_in_days
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health"
    name      = "HealthStreamingEnabled"
    value     = true
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health"
    name      = "DeleteOnTerminate"
    value     = var.logs_delete_on_terminate ? "true" : "false"
  }
}

#-------------------------------------------
# Adding DNS Configuration to Route53 Record
#-------------------------------------------

#use already available route53 zone
data "aws_route53_zone" "wty-report-service-route53-hosted-zone" {
  name         = var.hosted_zone_name
  private_zone = false
}

data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone" "current" {}

#create route53 recordset
resource "aws_route53_record" "wty-report-service-apigateway-recordset" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.wty-report-service-route53-hosted-zone.zone_id
  name    = var.dns_record_name
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = false
    name    = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.wty-report-service-dev.cname}"
    zone_id = "${data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone.current.id}"
  }
}

#-------------------------------------------
# Adding DNS Configuration to Route53 Record
#-------------------------------------------
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu_utilization" {
  alarm_name                = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.wty-report-service-app.name}-alarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
  period                    = "120"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "80"
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  dimensions = {
    InstanceId = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.wty-report-service-dev.instances[0]}"
  }
}
```

variables:

```
application_name             = "wty-report-service"
application_desc             = "Service application for Warranty Reports"
component                    = "wtyreports"
application_environment      = "devl"
bucket_name                  = "aws-wrs"
bucket_key                   = "wty-report/wty-report-service"
vpc_id                       = "vpc-"
service_subnets              = ["subnet-", "subnet-"] # Private Service Subnet
elb_public_subnets           = ["subnet-", "subnet-"] # ELB Public Subnet
security_groups              = ["sg-", "sg-", "sg-"] # 80 / 443 / 22
alb_security_groups          = ["sg-", "sg-"]
instance_type                = "t2.micro"
ec2_keypair_name             = "wty-report-service-key"
application_port             = "5000"
enable_http                  = false
loadbalancer_type            = "application"
elb_scheme                   = "internet-facing"
healthcheck_url              = "/WtyReport/health"
loadbalancer_ssl_policy      = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
build_source_filename        = "../../wty-report-service-build.zip"
tier                         = "WebServer"
autoscaling_update_policy    = {
  RollingUpdateType     = "Health",
  MinInstancesInService = "1",
  MaxBatchSize          = "1",
  RollingUpdateEnabled  = "false"
}
ebs_command_settings = {
  BatchSizeType    = "Fixed",
  BatchSize        = "1",
  DeploymentPolicy = "Rolling"
}
ebs_solution_stack = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.8 running Corretto 11"
env_vars           = {
  "SERVER_PORT" = "5000",
  "JAVA_HOME"   = "/usr/lib/jvm"
}
enable_stream_logs       = true
logs_delete_on_terminate = false
logs_retention_in_days   = 7

dns_record_name  = "wty-report-service"
hosted_zone_name = "devl-vpn.us.e06.c01.test.com"
```

Am I missing something here?